# component spliting in React causes TypeScript error

Tags: reactjs, typescript

The following React component is a form that displays the data of an element, wether it is a game or a team.

My component was working very well before I decided to split the Form from the query parent component.

Here are my interfaces :

```
export interface ShowProps {
  readOnly: boolean
  query: object
  id?: string | number
  match: {
    params: {
      id: string
      elements: string}
    }
}

//team
export interface Elem {
  id: string;
  name?: string;
  [attr: string]: string | number | undefined
}

//game
export interface Elem {
  id: string;
  homeTeamScore?: number
  competition?: string
  round?: string
}

export interface Data {
  elem?: Elem
  [elements: string]: Elem | undefined
}

export interface Variable {
  id?: string | number
}

export interface FormElemProps {
  data: object
  elementName: string
  readOnly: boolean
  listPath: string
}
```

---

This works perfectly (no TypeScript error) :

```
class FormElemQuery extends Query<Data, Variable> {}

const Show = (props: ShowProps) => {
  const id = props.match.params.id
  return (
    <FormElemQuery query={props.query} variables={{ id }}>
    {({ data = {}, error, loading }) => {
      // manage loading
      // manage error
      if (data !== {}  && Object.keys(data).length > 0 ) {
        const elementName = Object.keys(data)[0]
        return (
            <form>
            {
              Object.keys(data[elementName] || {}).map(attr => {
                if (attr !== "id" && attr !== "__typename") {
                  return (
                    <div key={attr} className="form-group">
                      <label htmlFor={`${Object.keys(data)[0]}-${attr}`}>{attr}</label>
                      <input
                        type="text"
                        readOnly={props.readOnly}
                        className="form-control"
                        id={`${Object.keys(data)[0]}-${attr}`}
                        value={data[elementName]![attr] || ""}
                        />
                    </div>
                  )
                }
            }
          )
        }
            </form>
        );
      }
    }}
  </FormElemQuery>
  )
}

export default Show;
```

---

But the split below does not work :

The parent component:

```
class ShowQuery extends Query<Data, Variable> {}

const Show = (props: ShowProps) => {
  const id = props.match.params.id
  return (
    <ShowQuery query={props.query} variables={{ id }}>
    {({ data = {}, error, loading }) => {
      // loading management
      // error management
      if (data !== {}  && Object.keys(data).length > 0 ) {
        const elementName = Object.keys(data)[0]
        return (
          <FormElem
            data={data}
            elementName={elementName}
            readOnly={props.readOnly}
            listPath={props.match.params.elements}
            />
        );
      }
    }}
    </ShowQuery>
  )
}

export default Show;
```

the Form component:

```
const FormElem = (props: FormElemProps) =>  {
  return (
            <form>
            {
              Object.keys(props.data[props.elementName]).map(attr => {
                if (attr !== "id" && attr !== "__typename") {
                  return (
                    <div key={attr} className="form-group">
                      <label htmlFor={`${Object.keys(props.data)[0]}-${attr}`}>{attr}</label>
                      <input
                        type="text"
                        readOnly={props.readOnly}
                        className="form-control"
                        id={`${Object.keys(props.data)[0]}-${attr}`}
                        value={props.data[props.elementName]![attr] || ""}
                        />
                    </div>
                  )
                }
            }
          )
        }
            </form>
        );
}

export default FormElem;
```

Here is the error I get when I run this code :

```
TypeScript error: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type '{}' has no index signature.  TS7017

    16 |             <form>
    17 |             {
  > 18 |               Object.keys(props.data[props.elementName]).map(attr => {
       |                           ^
    19 |                 if (attr !== "id" && attr !== "__typename") {
    20 |                   return (
    21 |                     <div key={attr} className="form-group">
```

So there is definitely something wrong with the use of props into Object.keys (as far as I understand, Object.keys is not indexable). But I don't know what to do to solve this.

Any idea ?

Comment: You have two `export interface Elem`s. Are you sure your code as pasted here is correct?

Comment: hi @AKX, thank you for you question. Yes it is made on purpose, it is [declaration merging](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html)

Comment: Sure, but I would just use `export interface Team extends Elem`...

Comment: yeah it makes sense ! I'll refactor my code using your advice; also I just found out what my problem was and it wasn't link with this, I'm gonna write an answer :)

Comment: Have you renamed in the question?  what is type `Element` ?

Comment: No I haven't :) I don't know what `Element` is, I have nothing in my code named like so; probably something from React or TS. I know it is confusing with my `Elem` interfaces though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So has I am using `data` when the component isn't split, and `props.data` in the `Form`when it is split, I had the change the way I define `data` within the `FormElemProps` interface:

```
export interface FormElemProps {
  data: {
    elem?: Elem
    [key: string]: Elem | undefined
  }
  // ...
}
```